# Background text color leaking over superimposed element

Tags: html, css

Having html: `<a href="">TEST</a>`

And css:

```
a {
  color: #222;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #222;
}

a::before {
  content: 'TE';
  position: absolute;
}

a:hover::before {
  color: red;
}
```

(Pastebin: http://jsbin.com/pefeweluli/edit?html,css,output )

What I'm trying to do is for the background text color to not leak over the red hover element, ideally without setting a background color for the ::before element.

Should I cave in and use an extra element or JS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited the post to have repro code inline

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it the other way around:

```
a {
  color: #222;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: #222;
}
a::before {
  content: 'ST';
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
a:hover::before {
  color: #fff;
}
```

It works, but it does have issues with padding